# Is the "lying over" relation of prime ideals preserved by lifting, aka reversing the quotient map?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading an algebra book and trying to fill in the details of a proof of the going up theorem for integral extensions. Let $R$ be a ring and $R^*$ is an integral extension of $R$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $R$, and let $\mathfrak{p}^*$ be a prime ideal lying over $\mathfrak{p}$.

Now, $R^* / p^*$ is integral extension of $R / p$, and suppose I have found ideals $\mathfrak{Q}$ in $R/p$ and $\mathfrak{Q}^*$ in $R^* / p^*$, such that $\mathfrak{Q}^*$ is lying over $\mathfrak{Q}$. These ideals can then be lifted back to $R^*$ and $R$ to give ideals $\mathfrak{q}^*$ and $\mathfrak{q}$. However, I have difficulty showing that $\mathfrak{q}^*$ is lying over $\mathfrak{q}$. I think I have managed to prove it by definitions, but it is really messy. **So the question is** is there a neat way to see this result?

More generally, what are the important properties that are preserved by taking quotients by prime ideals? In other parts of this book I find it difficult to follow some arguments that go like 'replacing $R$ and $R^*$ by $R_\mathfrak{p}$ and $R^*_{\mathfrak{p}}$, we have...', because I have to check that the hypotheses still apply to the reduced case, and once the result is shown in the reduced case, that it implies the result in the original case.

For example, for stuff like localization, i.e. an argument that goes like 'replacing $R$ and $R^*$ by $S^{-1} R$ and $S^{-1} R^*$...' I usually can convince myself that everything checks out, because seeing things as fractions are still quite simple.